# decoding and encoding strings, ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have read the other posts on this issue, but the solutions they presented did not work for me. Actually, the official Java documentation also did not work as intended (I am using Java 11) : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

My problem is that I am reading one byte at a time from a byte buffer, putting that in a byte array, and making a String out of that byte array. The bytes I read are from an embedded system that can only send ISO-8859-1 bytes, so I end up with a byte array with ISO-8859-1 bytes and the Java String I end up getting is thus ISO-8859-1 encoded. No problem here. The String in IntelliJ looks like this :

[image]

The bytes I am trying to convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 are the ones in yellow. I want them to be UTF-8, so in the end the "C9" byte should be replace by the "C3A9" bytes.

**The first step works correctly**, I do this : `maintenanceResponseString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and I get the right bytes that I want, the UTF-8 encoding of the string, that's good :

[image]

**The problem comes in here** , when I try to make a STRING out of these new (and GOOD) bytes, like this :

```
new String(maintenanceResponseString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

[image]

The **old bytes are back** ?!! It's like the "getBytes(UTF-8)" never actually happened. That is NOT what the documentation says should happen... what am I missing here ? I have done tests and the string really is still ISO-8859-1 encoded... I don't know what is going on here. Where are the bytes from "getBytes" ?

How do you convert a String that contains ISO-8859-1 bytes to UTF-8 bytes ? I'm out of alternatives and I need to get it done real bad for a pro project... this should be easy !

Note : I have tried alternatives like

```java
ByteBuffer buffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(s);
return StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer).toString();
```

But the exact same thing happens.

Thank you in advance for your help.

***EDIT :***
With some info in the comments about how Strings in Java 9+ get represented internally not as UTF-16 only anymore, but Latin-1 (why...), I think that is what made me think the Strings were "internally encoded in Latin-1" when it is just the default representation of the String **if we don't specify the encoding we want to use when displaying the String**.

From what I undestand now the String itself is **not bound to any encoding**, and you can CHOOSE the encoding you want to display it in when it gets written.
Actually my issue is that the String ends up written to an XML file via JAXB marshalling in LATIN-1, and I now think the issues lies over there... I will dig further when I access my work computer again and report here

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but [an online compiler does not show that either](https://onecompiler.com/java/3wnjdsk7e). Is there may be anything different you do compared to the sample?

Comment: There is no such thing as “a String that contains ISO-8859-1 bytes.”  Java is not C.  Strings are not sequences of bytes, they are sequences of characters. Strings are *always* UTF-16.  You can *decode* bytes to Strings using different Charsets, as you seem to know, but once you have a String object, it has only one encoding, period.  (Internally it may represent those characters in different ways, but code can only access those characters as UTF-16 `char` values or `int` codepoint values.)

Comment: Note that `new String(maintenanceResponseString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is the same as doing nothing at all.  It is a pointless round trip.

Comment: @VGR since java-9 they are stored internally as `byte[]` and the encoder is either `LATIN-1` or `UTF-16`, but yes, that is internally only.

Comment: “The first step works correctly…” Your first step doesn’t use StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 at all.  I find it highly unlikely that using `UTF_8` somehow decoded those ISO 8859-1 bytes correctly.

Comment: @VGR Further to the comment by Eugene, see [JEP 254: Compact Strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254). Strings may (or may not) still be represented with UTF-16 internally, but regardless they are now always stored as `byte[]`.

Comment: While you obviously put a lot of effort into your post I have a few suggestions meant constructively: [1] It is far too verbose and rambling. Delete the superfluous chatter. [2] Reduce the size and content of the screen shots to show less irrelevant data. [3] Embed your entire code within the question so we can just copy and paste exactly what you are doing. Readers shouldn't have to click a link, and if that link stops working your question is of very limited value. [4] Finally, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Eugene Ok so this is just a case when I am getting "tricked" by IntelliJ because it is showing me the internal representation of the string that is Latin-1 by default internally ? The screenshots are from the IntelliJ debugger. If I understand correctly, in Java a String is not bound to any encoding at all, and the encoding is chosen when we want to write the String down ? My use case is I write the String to an XML with JAXB, and it comes out as Latin-1... maybe the issue is that JAXB actually choses to write the String as Latin-1 ?

Comment: @VGR  "Your first step doesn’t use StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 at all ... " I know, I realized that using UTF-8 I actually obtained the UTF-8 bytes, so I used that... I didn't care about getting the Latin-1 bytes. I just want the String to come out as UTF-8 when written to a file by JAXB in the end... and yes I have set `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING,"UTF-8")`

Comment: Check out my EDIT :)

Comment: What does the first line of the file written by JAXB look like?  Is it an XML prologue, like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`?

Comment: Also, what code are you using when you call Marshaller.marshal?  Are you passing a `File` or are you opening a Writer yourself?

Comment: @VGR actually there is no prologue on the generated XML, we needed it to be like that as that XML then gets wrapped inside a SOAP request, and the request has the prologue. I marshal into a String directly as I didn't want the extra disk-io, and I think I used a "StringWriter" so I think maybe you have a point there, I will look at that part closer on monday thanks for your help I'll report on what I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with Strings and "their encoding". What happened is I got really confused because the debugger shows the contents of the String in a "default internal storage encoding", and that is ISO-8859-1 (but can be UTF-16, depends on the content of the String).

Quote from the [JEP-254](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) :

> We propose to change the internal representation of the String class
> from a UTF-16 char array to a byte array plus an encoding-flag field.
> The new String class will store characters encoded either as
> ISO-8859-1/Latin-1 (one byte per character), or as UTF-16 (two bytes
> per character), based upon the contents of the string. The encoding
> flag will indicate which encoding is used.

But actually it doesn't matter the internal encoding storage. When it is time to be written, the String **will use whatever encoding you want at the time of writing**.

My issue actually was when I was sending the String in an HTTP request with Spring RestTemplate. I didn't have the header specifying the "charset" to use in the request, and RestTemplate defaults to ISO-8859-1 if not told otherwise. I added the charset=utf-8, and the String was correctly written as UTF-8 in the request.

Thank you to @VGR @Eugene @skomisa for the help